# Unable to connect to host via SFTP in Java

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, jsch

I need to connect to a SFTP server located at https://aa.xyz.com/abc using Java. Currently, am using JSCH Java API to establish SFTP connection, but am getting UnknownHostException.

I read on some thread on StackOverflow that one should mention only the host part of the domain. If I pass only aa.xyz.com, then the program makes a connection to the SFTP server, however I need to connect to server located at aa.xyz.com/abc. Please help.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(credential.getUsername(), credential.getHost());
session.setPassword(credential.getPassword());
Properties config = new Properties();
config.setProperty("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
Path path = Paths.get(".");
channelSftp.ls(path.toString());
```

Comment: once login you can change remote directory using `channelSftp.cd("abc");`

Comment: @Saravana abc is not a directory. When I use the GUI to browse the SFTP server on [https://aa.xyz.com/abc](https://aa.xyz.com/abc), there are only 4 directories present over there and abc is not one of them.

Comment: You should read up on the different components of a URL. The /abc in the HTTPS URL is a path, but that could be mapped to any number of locations on the actual file system. It is not part of the host name though, so if you are trying to connect to that server via SSH, you must not specify it.